# Jquery - how i can get the video src value?

Tags: jquery, video

i need to get the value of a video and need to change in to new value... for that i used this function:

```
var video = $('#task2ResultVideo').get(0);

console.log($(video).attr('poster')); // i am getting this

    $(video).attr('src',function(num,val){
        console.log(num,val)        // i am not getting this..
    }) ​
```

HTML:

```
<video id="task2ResultVideo" autobuffer poster="img/task2-results-host-poster.jpg">
    <source src="Video/webm/Task_2.4a_Host_treated.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="Video/ogv/Task_2.4a_Host_treated.theora.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="Video/MP4/Task_2.4a_Host_treated.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>​
```

But i am not able to get the values. what is wrong with my code? in case if i get the value how can i change the src?

any suggestion please?

Comment: `<video>` tag doesn't have `src` attribute. Its children do have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zSCce/1/)**

```
$('video source').each(function(num,val){
    console.log($(this).attr('src'));        // i am not getting this..
    $(this).attr('src', 'newSourceValue')
});
```

Based on the comments by OP, changing the src filename

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zSCce/2/)**

```
$('video source').each(function(num,val){
    console.log($(this).attr('src'));        // i am not getting this..
    strSrc = $(this).attr('src'); 
    strPath = strSrc.substring(0, strSrc.lastIndexOf('/'));
    strExtenion = strSrc.substring(strSrc.lastIndexOf('.'));
    $(this).attr('src', strPath + "/" + "newFileName" + strExtenion );    
})​;
```

Comment: No, you are wrong, i need to keep the same path, just name of the file has to change. as well there is no change in file ext. (3 diff ext are there)

Answer (score 9):

your video tag has not any source attribute so you will never get it. Instead get src attribute of its inner source tags

```
$('video').find('Source:first').attr('src');
```

this will get the value of src attribute of first source tag inside video tag

Answer (score 1):

```
var video = $('#task2ResultVideo');

video.find('source').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('src'));
});​

// if you want to get array of the src
var arr = video.find('source').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('src');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(video).children().each(function(index) {
    console.log(index + " " + $(this).attr('src'));
});
```