# Find all video elements and manipulate source src

Tags: javascript, html, video, src

I have a site with multiple video elements. I must add `#t=0.1` to `src=""` of each video.

```
<div itemprop="video" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject" class="seovid">
    <object>
        <video width="640" controls controlsList="nodownload">
            <source src="https://www.xzy/bla.mp4">
            Dein Browser unterstützt keine HTML5 Videos oder Du nutzt eine veraltete Version.
              </video>
    </object>
    <h3 itemprop="name“>bla</h3>
    <p itemprop="description“>bla</p>
</div>
```

So I was looking around for hours now, finding things close to what I'm looking for but not working for me:

[Jquery - how i can get the video src value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952703/jquery-how-i-can-get-the-video-src-value)
[How to get video tag src using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241968/how-to-get-video-tag-src-using-javascript)

```
var vids = document.getElementsByTagName('video') 
// vids is an HTMLCollection
for( var i = 0; i < vids.length; i++ ){ 
    console.log( vids.item(i).src )
}
```

So `getElementsByTagName` is a good start. But how to get the `src` property?
And how to manipulate it to keep the actual video path and just add `sth` to the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want to append the `#t=0.1` to the source.
You can get the source tag elements by `getElementsByTagName('source)` and then get the src attribute.

Below is the code.

```js
var vids = document.getElementsByTagName('video') 
// vids is an HTMLCollection
for( var i = 0; i < vids.length; i++ ){ 
  //#t=0.1
   vids.item(i).getElementsByTagName('source')[i].src += "#t=0.1" ;
   console.log( vids.item(i).getElementsByTagName('source')[i].src);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div itemprop="video" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject" class="seovid">
 <object>
  <video width="640" controls controlsList="nodownload">
   <source src="https://www.xzy/bla.mp4">
   Dein Browser unterstützt keine HTML5 Videos oder Du nutzt eine veraltete Version.
          </video>
 </object>
 <h3 itemprop="name“>bla</h3>
 <p itemprop="description“>bla</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you provided, the src is not on the video tag.
 It's an attribute of tag source. 
You can get a value of an attribute in javascript by using **getAttribute('NameOfTheAttribute')**. 
Below is the correct js

```js
var vids = document.getElementsByTagName('source') 
// vids is an HTMLCollection
for( var i = 0; i < vids.length; i++ ){ 
    console.log( vids.item(i).getAttribute('src') )
}
```

**fiddle:**  https://jsfiddle.net/xldlx/yw4fzmk1/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div itemprop="video" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject" class="seovid">
     <object>
       <video width="640" controls controlsList="nodownload">
          <source src="https://www.xzy/bla.mp4">
       Dein Browser unterstützt keine HTML5 Videos oder Du nutzt eine veraltete Version.
       </video>
       </object>
       <h3 itemprop="name“>bla</h3>
       <p itemprop="description“>bla</p>
    </div>










var vids = document.getElementsByTagName('video') 
// vids is an HTMLCollection
for( var i = 0; i < vids.length; i++ ){ 
   vids[i].children[0].setAttribute('src', vids[i].children[0].src+'#0.1');
}
```